# iOS 7 iPad Guided Access Text Areas dont show keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, guided-access

For the life of me I cant figure this out - please help me :)

Basically I'm hoping to use some ipads as a kiosk solution to gather data in public areas however whenever I enable guided access mode and tap a textArea the soft keyboard doesnt show up. Heres the steps:

Goto Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access > Enable
Goto Safari > Open Google.com > Triple tap the home button > Resume

Incorrect Behaviour:
Tap the search screen > No keyboard shows

I've tested this with a "New" iPad (last of the old dock connector models) & iPad Air on 7.0.6

Also tested on iPhone 5S on 7.1 and it seems fine (so two variables there)

Can anyone confirm/deny my thoughts it may be a bug

Comment: I can confirm the behavior for iOS versions before the 7.1 update. I've tested with the latest iPad Air, and everything works fine with 7.1. Another problem was that when the keyboard was visible when resuming guided access, it could not be hidden any more.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug in iOS 7 versions below 7.1. With iOS 7.1 automatically showing the keyboard when selecting an input textfield worked as well as the "hide keyboard" button when resuming guided access while the keyboard is visible.

I'm not aware of a workaround for this behavior for iOS 7 versions before iOS 7.1.